# C++ variadic templates of different input type using c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Recently I do a research about modern c++. I saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gycxew-hztI) [in 49:00] about c++11/c++14 variadic templates. If you want to calculate the sum of tuple ofdifferent types(such as `int`, `double`) with variadic templates, using c++11, the video suggest a solution:

```
struct Sum
{
    template<typename T>
    static T sum(T n)
    {
        return n;
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    static auto sum(T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(n+sum(rest...))
    {
        return n + sum(rest...);
    }
}
auto x = Sum::sum(1, 2.5, 3);
```

`auto` can not deduce return type in `c++11`, so you have to declare return type using `decltype`. But some compiler build failed, some compiler build successfully.[link](https://godbolt.org/g/Vr4vqH)

Although, using `auto to deduce return type` has no problem, my question is:

1. Has `c++11` standard covered this question? If not, do the compilers deal with the problem by its own implementation?
2. Why do the newest version `gcc 8.1` compile failed, whereas `gcc 4/5/6/7` compile successfully? Is there any compatibility problem in gcc?

By the way, the compile error message is:

> test.cc:20:16: error: no matching function for call to 'sum'
>
> ```
>  double x = Sum::sum(1, 2.5, 3);
> ```
>
> test.cc:12:17: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = int, Args = ]: use of undeclared identifier 'sum'
>
> ```
>  static auto sum(T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(n + sum(rest...))
> ```
>
> test.cc:6:14: note: candidate function template not viable: requires
>   single argument 'n', but 3 arguments were provided
>
> ```
> static T sum(T n)
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me.  It appears as if the compiler is trying to reuse the same instantiation of `sum` in the deduced return type.

Comment: This uses 'struct Sum` as a namespace. I would change it to `namespace Sum` and remove the `static`'s.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Not bug. Feature.

Answer (score 7):

The function-name lookup in the trailing return type here,

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
static auto sum(T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(n+sum(rest...))
```

is done in the context of immediately before this `sum` is declared, plus via ADL (argument dependent lookup).

And as this template is not visible via ADL at the point of invocation on the types in question, it is proper for this to fail to compile.

The older gcc compilers probably used the object context in addition to the contexts they are supposed to.  That is a reasonable error to make.

You can fix this easily:

```
struct Sum {
private:
  template<typename T>
  friend T summer(Sum, T n) {
    return n;
  }
  template<typename T, typename... Args>
  friend auto summer(Sum, T n, Args... rest) -> decltype(n+summer(Sum{},rest...)) {
    return n + summer(Sum{},rest...);
  }
public:
  template<class...Args>
  auto sum(Args...args)->decltype(summer(Sum{}, args...)){
    return summer(Sum{}, args... );
  }
};
```

here we force ADL in some private friends.  This permits the overloads of summer to "see themselves" in their trailing return type.

Comment: Well done. You might want to add some universal reference `&&` stuff.

Comment: "The Overloads of Summer" - Isn't that a Hemingway novel?

Comment: Good job, Yakk. I tried this solution, `gcc 8.1`  works, but clang doesn't work. see [link](https://godbolt.org/g/xLExub).  So the key point of these diffrences is `function-name lookup`, isn't it?

Comment: Why does this fix work? In other words why does adding a dummy tag and making a friend help force ADL?

Comment: @0x4996 The standard?  Function names are looked up in two contexts.  One is frozen at function definition; ADL at instantiation.  Friend is not what forces ADL, friend lets me keep private details private.